# When does the singular value decomposition fail?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, random-matrices

Does the singular value decomposition ever not work? The statement of the associated theorem, here from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Statement_of_the_theorem), is surprisingly general. Are there certain conditions of the matrix $M$ that would make the decomposition fail to exist? The matrix M in question is a random matrix that is point-wise convergent.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every real matrix has an SVD with real entries, every complex matrix has an SVD with complex entries. There are no further conditions.

Comment: That is amazing! Thank you!